# How to show injectivity of a function?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Here's what I'm trying to prove: `Theorem add_n_injective : forall n m p, n + m = n + p -> m = p.`

The `+` is notation for `plus`, defined as in https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Basics.html:

```
Fixpoint plus (n : nat) (m : nat) : nat :=
  match n with
    | O ⇒ m
    | S n' ⇒ S (plus n' m)
  end.
```

In Agda, one can do `cong (n + _)` to use the fact that `n + m = n + p` for any n m p.

Coq's built-in tactices `injection` and `congruence` both seemed promising, but they only work for constructors.

I tried the following strategy and kept hitting weird errors or getting stuck:

- make an inductive type for bundling up a proof of (n + m = s): Sum (n m s)
- use the `congruence` tactic in a lemma that shows `Sum (n m s) = Sum (n p s)`
- use constructing `Sum`s, `destruct`, and the lemma to show that n + m = n + p

Is there an easier way to prove this? I feel like there must be some built-in tactic I'm missing or some trickery with `unfold`.

**UPDATE**

Got it:

```
Theorem add_n_injective : forall n m p, n + m = n + p -> m = p.
Proof.
  intros. induction n.
  - exact H.
  - apply IHn.  (* goal: n + m = n + p *)
    simpl in H. (* H: S (n + m) = S (n + p) *)
    congruence.
Qed.
```

Thanks @ejgallego

Comment: The Agda cong tactic also will not prove this goal. (It can show  `m=p -> n+m=n+p`, but not `n+m=n+p -> m=p`.) In both Agda and coq you'll have to do an induction on n.

Comment: More compact proof `now induction n; [|injection 1].`

Comment: @ejgallego,  I tried `Proof. intros. now induction n; [|injection 1]. ` and got "No 1st non dependent hypothesis in current goal even after
head-reduction."

Comment: @MaxHeiber do `intros n m p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injectivity of `plus` is not an "elementary" statement, given that the `plus` function could be arbitrary (and non-injective)

I'd say the standard proof does require `induction` on the left argument, indeed using this method the proof quickly follows.

You will need `injection` when you arrive to a goal of the form `S (n + m) = S (n + p)` to derive the inner equality.